# Where do Gulp events come from

Tags: gulp

I've just worked with Gulp and seeing this:

```
gulp.src('..')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('..'))
    .on('end', function() { });
```

I want to know where the `end` event is declared and the full list of events like `start`, `end` ... ?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gulp's streams are just regular [Node.js streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) that operate in [object mode](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_object_mode). The objects emitted in those streams are [vinyl file objects](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl).

More specifically gulp's streams are of type [`stream.Transform`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform) meaning they implement both the [`stream.Readable`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) and [`stream.Writable`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable) interfaces. As such they support all the events supported by those two types:

`stream.Readable`

- [`'close'` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_close):

  > Emitted when the stream and any of its underlying resources (a file descriptor, for example) have been closed.
- [`'data'` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data):

  > switch the stream into flowing mode. Data will then be passed as soon as it is available.
- [`'end'` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end):

  > This event fires when there will be no more data to read.
- [`'error'` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_error):

  > Emitted if there was an error receiving data.
- [`'readable'` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_readable):

  > When a chunk of data can be read from the stream

`stream.Writable`

- [`'close'` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_close_1):

  > Emitted when the stream and any of its underlying resources (a file descriptor, for example) have been closed.
- [`'drain'` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_drain):

  > If a `stream.write(chunk)` call returns `false`, then the `'drain'` event will indicate when it is appropriate to begin writing more data to the stream.
- [`'error'` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_error_1):

  > Emitted if there was an error when writing or piping data.
- [`'finish'` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish):

  > When the `stream.end()` method has been called, and all data has been flushed to the underlying system
- [`'pipe'` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_pipe):

  > emitted whenever the `stream.pipe()` method is called
- [`'unpipe'` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_unpipe):

  > emitted whenever the `stream.unpipe()` method is called

Comment: Thank you so much !